# Getting an editable text from UIImage of text in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to develop an application in which I capture an image of text (a business card, for example), and now I want it to be scanned and converted into an editable text. Is it possible? Something like optical character recognition.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples

1. OpenCV library for Apple iOS. It includes two XCode projects: one for iPhone, the other one for iPad [Try OpenCV with iOS](http://code.google.com/p/opencv-ios/)
2. demo application that utilizes the Tesseract library as a static library compiled under Mac OS 10.6 [Try Tesseract with iOS](https://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo)
3. And [Here is good question realte to this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062755/ocroptical-character-recoginition-libraries-for-iphone)

Hope this information should be useful for you.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide links in comments not as an answer.

Comment: I did't get as you are mentioning +1 ?

Comment: @BuntyMadan it means "Nice answer you've given very useful links for that 1 upvote for your answer from me" :)

Comment: :) thanks but there is only 1 upvote and this given by someOne another before your comment that's why. after all thanks a lot Young man for your complement. Good to see your response.

Comment: Actually you got 2 upvote. And someone else has also down voted here. Without reason.

Comment: The problem is we can't see who Upvote/DownVote our Questions/Answers. Some peoples do this without any reason. as someOne did with your answer.

Comment: Haha.. Individual's thinking buddy can't do much about it :)